# PHP - Large POST Request Server Error

Tags: php, post, request, webserver, iis-8

For my Webserver I'm using IIS8 on a Windows Server 2012 with ASP.NET, PHP7+ and FastCGI.

My problem: When I try to submit a formular (HTML to PHP) with a value string, in thic case longer than 20.000 characters, the server returns a 500 Server Error **OR** it doesn't recognize the post request at all.

My HTML/PHP Code:

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo "Got it!"; } ?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" value="String with 20000+ characters" name="value">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

By clicking submit the server error comes up. Within the post request these lines are inserted in the PHP Error Log File:

```html
[] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory. in Unknown on line 0
[] PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST data can't be buffered; all data discarded in Unknown on line 0
```

I also **edited all configuration options** that may be in connection with this.

php.ini

```
post_max_size = 1024M
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

web.config on my server

```
<system.web><httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>

    <security>
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
</requestFiltering>
```

Thanks for any support.

Comment: It sounds like the permissions error might actually be related to either your log or cache files. Check the permissions of the `storage` folder to see if the system has write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal type :

```
chmod -R 777 /your/upload/folder
```

you can know the folder where your php uploads files by executing this code :

```
$tmp_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') : sys_get_temp_dir();
die($tmp_dir);
```

In my case I get /var/... so when I sett 777 permission I get no error.

Comment: 1. It's not a good idea to give execute permissions to your PHP upload folder!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the hard drive was full. So no space to even write temporary data. After deleting some files everything did POST again.